# Adding records to WooCommerce tables via MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, wordpress

This is more of a MySQL query question, but those with experience working with WooCommerce might have some valuable insight.

I'm trying to create a stored procedure and running into some syntax issues.  The MySQL error message states a syntax error on line 60.  But after commenting out line by line, it seems to not like the DECLARE line. Any help would be appreciated.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_AddProduct$$

create procedure sp_AddProduct (
  IN PostDate datetime,
  IN PostParent int,
  IN SKU varchar(10),
  IN Weight int,
  IN Price Decimal(5,2),
  IN Size varchar(10),
  IN GUID varchar(250),
  IN MenuOrder int
)
BEGIN


  INSERT INTO wp_posts (
    post_author,
    post_date, 
    post_date_gmt, 
    post_content, 
    post_title, 
    post_excerpt, 
    post_status, 
    comment_status, 
    ping_status, 
    post_password, 
    post_name, 
    to_ping, 
    pinged, 
    post_modified, 
    post_modified_gmt, 
    post_content_filtered, 
    post_parent, 
    guid, 
    menu_order, 
    post_type, 
    post_mime_type, 
    comment_count
  ) 
  VALUES (
    '1',
    PostDate,
    PostDate,
    '',
    '',
    '',
    'publish',
    'open',
    'open',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    PostDate,
    PostDate,
    '',
    PostParent,
    GUID,
    MenuOrder,
    'product_variation',
    '',
    0
  )$$


  /* Set the PostID = the PostID generated from the above insert*/
  DECLARE PostID int$$
  set PostID = LAST_INSERT_ID()$$

  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_sku',SKU)$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_thumbnail_id',0)$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_virtual','no')$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_downloadable','no')$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_weight',Weight)$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_length','')$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_width','')$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_height','')$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_manage_stock','no')$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_stock_status','instock')$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_regular_price',Price)$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_sale_price','')$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_sale_price_dates_from','')$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_sale_price_dates_to','')$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_price',Price)$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_download_limit','')$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_download_expiry','')$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_downloadable_files','')$$
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_attribute_pa_size',Size)$$

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the following changes:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_AddProduct$$

create procedure sp_AddProduct (
  IN PostDate datetime,
  IN PostParent int,
  IN SKU varchar(10),
  IN Weight int,
  IN Price Decimal(5,2),
  IN Size varchar(10),
  IN GUID varchar(250),
  IN MenuOrder int
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE PostID int;

  INSERT INTO wp_posts (
    post_author,
    post_date, 
    post_date_gmt, 
    post_content, 
    post_title, 
    post_excerpt, 
    post_status, 
    comment_status, 
    ping_status, 
    post_password, 
    post_name, 
    to_ping, 
    pinged, 
    post_modified, 
    post_modified_gmt, 
    post_content_filtered, 
    post_parent, 
    guid, 
    menu_order, 
    post_type, 
    post_mime_type, 
    comment_count
  ) 
  VALUES (
    '1',
    PostDate,
    PostDate,
    '',
    '',
    '',
    'publish',
    'open',
    'open',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    PostDate,
    PostDate,
    '',
    PostParent,
    GUID,
    MenuOrder,
    'product_variation',
    '',
    0
  );/*$$*/

  /* Set the PostID = the PostID generated from the above insert*/
  -- DECLARE PostID int$$
  set PostID = LAST_INSERT_ID();/*$$*/    

  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_sku',SKU);/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_thumbnail_id',0);/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_virtual','no');/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_downloadable','no');/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_weight',Weight);/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_length','');/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_width','');/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_height','');/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_manage_stock','no');/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_stock_status','instock');/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_regular_price',Price);/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_sale_price','');/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_sale_price_dates_from','');/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_sale_price_dates_to','');/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_price',Price);/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_download_limit','');/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_download_expiry','');/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_downloadable_files','');/*$$*/
  INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (PostID,'_attribute_pa_size',Size);/*$$*/
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```